# Uniformly Choosing a number from a range

Tags: statistics, uniform-distribution

May you please help me how I can choose uniformly a number from a range. I have to use this for trust evaluation in social networks such as the following clause:

> Each user has a quality measurement qi ∈ [0, 1]. For the experiments
>   in this paper, the quality of a user is chosen from a normal
>   distribution. For any pair of users, i and j, the trust rating from
>   node i to node j, denoted as T (i, j), is uniformly chosen from
>   [max(qj − δij, 0), min(qj + δij, 1)]. In addition, δij = (1 − qi)/2 is
>   a noise parameter that determines how accurate users are at estimating
>   the quality of the user that they are trusting

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Any of the common programming languages has such a function build in, otherwise you can google it and there are some websites that provide for you.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=rand+number+in+range+0+to+1

Comment: You mean that uniformly choosing a number from a range, is randomly choose a number from a range?

Comment: i mean that yes